# Pass jQuery to .animate Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I've setup a simple animator method like so:

```
Animator: function (obj, aniArgs, duration, aniEasArgs, completeFunction) {
    obj.stop(true, true).animate(aniArgs, {
        duration: duration,
        queue: false,
        specialEasing: aniEasArgs,
        complete: function () {
            if (completeFunction !== null) {

            };
        }
    });
    return obj;
},
```

What I'd like to do is be able to pass in string of jQuery to run in the complete callback. Everything else works fine. How, for example, would I pass in

```
$('#someElement').hide(500);
```

into the callback?

Thanks!

Comment: Just call `completeFunction()`?

Comment: I'll be using this function to call different animations on different elements. So Plugin.Animator(element,{'opacity':0.5}, 500, {'opacity':'linear'}, " .... ")    The ... is where the callback info (such as $('#someElement').hide(500) would need to go. I'm not sure I follow you by calling completeFunction()?

Comment: how is `Animator` called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a function with the code you want to run:

```
function complete() {
    $('#someElement').hide(500);
}
```

Then, pass that function in when you call Animator:

```
Animator( obj, aniArgs, duration, aniEasArgs, complete );
```

Or, you can put the function inline:

```
Animator( obj, aniArgs, duration, aniEasArgs, function() {
    $('#someElement').hide(500);
});
```

Those both work the same way, you can use either style depending on what makes your code easier to read.

Either way, change your Animator code to:

```
        if( completeFunction ) {
            completeFunction();
        };
```

Or, you'll often see that written this way:

```
        completeFunction && completeFunction();
```

They both do exactly the same thing. It's just a matter of taste which you use, just thought I'd mention both variations so you'll recognize them when you see them.

Note that the `!== null` test is not required here, and in fact isn't what you want. That's because if the caller does not pass in a `completeFunction`, the value of that variable will be `undefined`, not `null`, so your test won't work. Interestingly enough, you can use `!= null` in this case, because that will test for both `null` and `undefined` and treat them the same. But really you just don't need this explicit test at all, if the only thing you're checking for is whether the caller provided a `completeFunction` callback or not.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, and it maintains readability quite well too :)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Also I just added a couple more relevant notes to the answer.

Comment: @orb - No worries, it happens to the best of us. Just last night I posted a simple jQuery call that was completely wrong! Luckily the OP on that question caught my error and was quite gracious about it too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Animator: function (obj, aniArgs, duration, aniEasArgs, completeFunction) {
    obj.stop(true, true).animate(aniArgs, {
        duration: duration,
        queue: false,
        specialEasing: aniEasArgs,
        complete: function () {
            if (jQuery.isFunction(completeFunction )) {
                completeFunction.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        }
    });
    return obj;
},
```

Theb

```
x.Animator(obj, aniArgs, duration, aniEasArgs, function(){
    $('#someElement').hide(500);
})
```